# Decomposing floating-point division into integer and fractional part

Tags: c++, division, modulo, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to do integer division + modulo using doubles (for spline-based interpolation), but I've encountered some issues relating to floating-point precision when using `std::floor` and `std::fmod`.

I've been using the equivalent of `div1` below, but at 50 it produces incorrect results (that is, the integer part is 3, but the modulo part is the divisor minus epsilon). `div2` works but is rather convoluted. `div3` is at least consistent, but does not return the type of result I would like (the remainder may be negative, so it would need futher manipulation before I could use it).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

std::pair<double, double> div1(int num, double denom){
    double whole = std::floor(num / denom);
    double remain = std::fmod(num, denom);
    return {whole, remain};
}
std::pair<double, double> div2(int num, double denom){
    double floatdiv = num / denom;
    double whole;
    double remain = std::modf(floatdiv, &whole);
    return {whole, remain * denom};
}
std::pair<double, double> div3(int num, double denom){
    double whole = std::round(num / denom);
    double remain = std::remainder(num, denom);
    return {whole, remain};
}
int main() {
    double denom = 100.0 / 6;
    int divtype = 0;
    for(auto div: {div1, div2, div3}){
        std::cerr << "== Using div" << ++divtype << " for this run ==\n";
        for(int i = 40; i <= 60; ++i){
            auto res = div(i, denom);
            std::cerr << i << ": " << res.first << ", " << res.second << " = " << res.first * denom + res.second << "\n";
        }
        auto oldprec = std::cerr.precision(64);
        auto res = div(50, denom);
        std::cerr << 50 << ": " << res.first << ", " << res.second << " = " << res.first << " * " << denom << " + " << res.second << " = " << std::floor(res.first) * denom + res.second << "\n";
        std::cerr.precision(oldprec);
        std::cerr << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/9UbHcE

For the case of 50, the following results are produced:

```
 - div1: 3, 16.6666... 
 - div2: 3, 0
 - div3: 3, -3e-15
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is `std::floor(num / denom)` + `std::fmod(num, denom)` not reliable? If so, what is a good replacement? Is `div2` the best option?

Version of code example with most answers included:
https://ideone.com/l2wGRj

Comment: And it would probably help to include relevant output (particularly the results of `floor()` and `fmod()`), and an explicit statement of what it is about `div3`'s output you don't like.

Comment: @PaulEvans What do you mean? The post appears to be unedited and already has an MCVE? Posting a link to an online compiler is just extra courtesy...

Comment: Perhaps you could take some inspiration from Boost.Rational. It's stated there that the library doen't offer floating point to rational conversion exactly because of precision issues.

Comment: Just use the `std::modf()` one. `std::fmod()` is one of those tricky functions that doesn't do quite what people assume it does.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Problem with linking outside of stackoverflow is that those links can go away, change, anything (*i.e.* they're not controlled by stackoverflow) so in courtesy or not they're not best practice.

Comment: @PaulEvans The **full** MCVE code is right there in the question (which is a rarity to say the least). The question gets objectively worse by removing the link. I do not understand what action you want the asker to take in this case, seeing as they already did the MCVE part perfectly - can you tell me?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Then the link is not only volatile but redundant.

Comment: @PaulEvans: [The StackOverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says “If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, thought it was frowned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your core problem is that `denom = 100.0/6` is not the same as the mathematically exact value `denomMath = 100/6 = 50/3`, because it can't be represented as a sum of powers of two. We can write `denom = denomMath + eps` (with a small positive or negative epsilon). After assigning it, `denom` is indistinguishable from the closest floating point number! If you now try to divide some value `denomMath * k = denom * k + eps * k` by `denom`, for a sufficiently large `k` you will get the wrong result *mathematically* (i.e. in exact arithmetic) already - you have no hope in this case. How soon this happens depends on the magnitudes involved (if the values are < 1 then all your `div` will yield whole parts of zero and be exact, whereas for values larger than `2^54` you cannot even represent odd numbers).

But even before that, there is no guarantee that dividing a (mathematical) multiple of `denomMath` by `denom` yields something that can be `floor`ed or `fmod`ed to the right whole number. Rounding might keep you safe for a while, but as shown above, only as long as the errors don't get too large.

So:

- `div1` runs into the problem described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod

  > The expression `x - trunc(x/y)*y` may not equal `fmod(x,y)` when the rounding of `x/y` to initialize the argument of `trunc` loses too much precision (example: `x = 30.508474576271183309`, `y = 6.1016949152542370172`)

  In your case, `50 / denom` yields a number that is slightly too large (`3`) compared to the exact result (`3 - some epsilon` because `denom` is slightly larger than `denomMath`)

  You cannot rely on `std::floor(num / denom) + std::fmod(num, denom)` to equal `num`.
- `div2` has the problem described above: In your case it works, but if you try more cases you'll find one where `num / denom` is slightly too small instead of too large and it will fail too.
- `div3` has promise as mentioned above. It actually gives you the most precise result you could hope for.

Comment: So, div3 plus checking the remainder for negativity, compensating by adding the denominator to the remainder, and decrementing the whole would be your recommendation?

Comment: I didn't make a recommendation because I didn't investigate whether this approach brings new problems (such as catastrophic cancellation from subtracting two closeby numbers), but I think your suggestion should be safe here indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with your `fmod` but with your input to `floor`. It's fine for `fmod` to return something close to the denominator due to floating-point precision fuzziness. The issue is that you have to be careful to treat the quotient using the same rules as the remainder so that the results come out to  (using fuzzy equality):

`x/y == (quot, rem) == quot * y + rem`

To illustrate, I've added `div4` and `div5`:

```cpp
std::pair<double, double> div4( int num,  double denom){
    int quo;
    auto rem = std::remquo(num, denom, &quo );
    return {quo, rem};
}

std::pair<double, double> div5( int num,  double denom){
    auto whole = std::floor(num / static_cast<long double>( denom ) );
    auto remain = std::fmod(num, denom);
    return {whole, remain};
}
```

Here is a [slimmed-down version of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58b7e96c067e1dca) just focusing on the failure case. The output is:

```
div1: 50 / 16.6666666666666678509 = (whole, remain) = (3, 16.6666666666666642982) = 66.6666666666666571928
...
div4: 50 / 16.6666666666666678509 = (whole, remain) = (3, -3.55271367880050092936e-15) = 50
div5: 50 / 16.6666666666666678509 = (whole, remain) = (2, 16.6666666666666642982) = 50
```

For `div1`, you got a whole of 3 and remainder of (almost) one divisor. The error is that the value sent into `floor` is right on the line due to floating-point fuzziness and so gets bumped UP to 3, where it should really be 2.

If you use my `div5`, which uses [`std::remquo`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remquo) to compute the remainder and quotient at the same time, you'll get the similar pair `(2, ~divisor)` which then all multiplies correctly back to 50. (Note that the quotient comes back as an integer, not a floating-point number from that standard function.) [**Update**: As noted in the comments, this is only valid for 3 bits of precision in the quotient, which is to say that it is useful for periodic functions needing to detect quadrant or octant, but not the general quotient.]

Or if you use my `div4`, I used your `div1` logic but upgraded the input to `floor` to `long double` precision before the division operation, which gives it enough digits to evaluate the floor correctly. The result is `(3, ~0)`, which shows the fuzziness in the remainder rather than in the quotient.

The `long double` approach ultimately just kicks the can down the road to the same problem at some higher precision. Using `std::remquo` is more numerically reliable for limited cases of periodic functions. Which version you choose will be determined by what you care more about: numerical computation or pretty display.

**Update**: You can also try to detect when things have gone awry by using the FP exceptions:

```cpp
void printError()
{
    if( std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO)  ) std::cout << "pole error occurred in an earlier floating-point operation\n";
    if( std::fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT)    ) std::cout << "inexact result: rounding was necessary to store the result of an earlier floating-point operation\n";
    if( std::fetestexcept(FE_INVALID)    ) std::cout << "domain error occurred in an earlier floating-point operation\n";
    if( std::fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW)   ) std::cout << "the result of the earlier floating-point operation was too large to be representable\n";
    if( std::fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW)  ) std::cout << "the result of the earlier floating-point operation was subnormal with a loss of precision\n";
}

// ...
// Calling code
std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
const auto res = div(i, denom);
printError();
// ...
```

This reports `inexact result: rounding was necessary to store the result of an earlier floating-point operation` for functions 1, 2, 3, and 5. See it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e778b8b74cbeafef)</kbd>.

Comment: What I care about is smooth concatenation of a number of gradients (smooth blending between a series of colors). The numerical issues can cause the join between the gradients to be of entirely the wrong color (color of the next join). `std::remquo` would seem like a good option, but it only guarantees 3 bits, and I may have more than 8 segments to join.

Comment: You are right about `std::remquo` not being sufficient for non-periodic cases. I added an update about checking floating-point exceptions, but you may find `long double` is sufficient for your case if you're needing lots of precision. If not, you might consider switching to a library solution to has large, fixed or even infinite precision, but this will be slower if it is not relying on the processor's FP instructions.

Answer (score 1):

For positive numerators and denominators, the mathematically exact quotient and remainder can be calculated with the following code, as long as the quotient does not exceed the significand of the floating-point format (2<sup>53</sup> for the typical `double`):

```
std::pair<double, double> divPerfect(int num, double denom)
{
    double whole = std::floor(num / denom);
    double remain = std::fma(whole, -denom, num);
    if (remain < 0)
    {
        --whole;
        remain = std::fma(whole, -denom, num);
    }
    return {whole, remain};
}
```

Reasoning:

- If the exact `num` / `denom` is an integer, it is representable, and `num / denom` must produce it, and `std::floor(num / denom)` has the same value. Otherwise, `num / denom` may round up or down slightly, which cannot reduce `std::floor(num / denom)` but may increase it by one. Therefore, `double whole = std::floor(num / denom)` gives us either the proper quotient or one more.
- If `whole` is correct, then `std::fma(whole, -denom, num)` is exact, because the exact mathematical answer has magnitude less than `denom` or equal to `whole` (if `whole` < `denom`), and its least significant bit is at least as great as the available least significant bit position in `denom` or `whole`, respectively, so all of its bits fit in the floating-point format, so it is representable and therefore must be produced as the result. Further, this remainder is non-negative.
- If `whole` is one too high, then `std::fma(whole, -denom, num)` is negative (but still exact, as above). Then we correct `whole` and repeat the `std::fma` to get an exact result.

I expect the second `std::fma` can be avoided:

```
std::pair<double, double> divPerfect(int num, double denom)
{
    double whole = std::floor(num / denom);
    double remain = std::fma(whole, -denom, num);
    return 0 <= remain ? std::pair(whole, remain) : std::pair(whole - 1, remain + denom);
}
```

However, I would want to think about it a bit more to be sure.

Comment: The issue in the question primarily stems from `denom` already being inexact. Doing "perfect" division with an imperfect `denom` is not going to fix that - you'll not get `(10.0, 0.0)` for `num = 1` and `denom = 0.1` because the actually represented `denom` is slightly larger than `0.1` and thus does not fit 10 times into (the accurately representable) 1.0.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: No, it does not. The OP stated in a comment “What I care about is smooth concatenation of a number of gradients (smooth blending between a series of colors).” This means they do not need a mathematically perfect quotient and remainder for hypothetical exact numerator and denominator but need a self-consistent quotient and remainder for the actual numerator and denominator they have.

Answer (score 0):

This *does* feel like it could be a bug in the implementation of `fmod()`. According to the definition on [std::fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) on cppreference.com:

> The floating-point remainder of the division operation x/y calculated by this function is exactly the value x - n*y, where n is x/y with its fractional part truncated

I therefore added:

```
std::pair<double, double> div4(int num, double denom){
    double whole = std::floor(num / denom);
    int n = trunc(num / denom) ;
    double remain = num - n * denom ;
    return {whole, remain};
}
```

and looking at the output for just `div1` and `div4` from `49` to `51` I get<sup>**1**</sup>:

```
== Using div1 for this run ==
49: 2, 15.6667 = 49
50: 3, 16.6667 = 66.6667
51: 3, 1 = 51
50: 3, 16.66666666666666429819088079966604709625244140625 = 3 * 16.666666666666667850904559600166976451873779296875 + 16.66666666666666429819088079966604709625244140625 = 66.666666666666657192763523198664188385009765625

== Using div4 for this run ==
49: 2, 15.6667 = 49
50: 3, 0 = 50
51: 3, 1 = 51
50: 3, 0 = 3 * 16.666666666666667850904559600166976451873779296875 + 0 = 50
```

Which does give the desired results.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Because it is all I had immediately to hand, the output above was generated by running the original code through [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) which uses clang to convert the code into JavaScript that was then run with node.js. As this produced the same "problem" with the original code, I expect/hope my `div4` would do the same if compiled to native code.

Comment: The documentation seems to mean "the exact mathematical `x/y`" in the passage you quoted, which is not what you are passing `trunc`or `std::floor`. In fact, the documentation goes out of its way to document this exact issue: `The expression x - trunc(x/y)*y may not equal fmod(x,y) when the rounding of x/y to initialize the argument of trunc loses too much precision (example: x = 30.508474576271183309, y = 6.1016949152542370172) `